# Trying to pass a list and return a map using JDBC Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am trying to use JDBC template but I am not familiar with it very much.
I have a list of car makes that match to multiple car models. My database query is very simple ie.

```
    select * from Model m,Make mk where m.model_id = mk.model_id And ml_name IN (:modelname)
```

I have a list of Models that I want to pass in the JDBC template and to return a Map of String,List by which I mean all makes and List of their models.
It may sound like I am making someone to spoon feed me but I will use the replies to learn.

Comment: have you ever tried google search ?  there must be millions of examples out there..

Answer (score 0):

I exactly don't know your data structure but what you are trying to do can be done by something as follows

```
jdbcTemplate.query("select m.name as model, mk.name maker from Model m,Make mk where m.model_id = mk.model_id And ml_name IN (:modelname)", Arrays.asList('suv', 'sedane', 'zip'), (ResultSet rs) -> {
    HashMap<String,List<String>> results = new HashMap<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (results.get(rs.getString('maker')) == null) {
            reslts.put(rs.getString('maker'), new ArrayList<>());
        }
        results.get(rs.getString('maker')).add(rs.getString("model"));
    }

    return results;
});
```

Comment: Instead of just SUV.   How can I pass a list

Comment: @Yourfavouritenoob Updated my code see if you can understand it now.

Comment: thank you for your effort. But it said it does't recognize the labmda expression.

Comment: Then you might be running on Java 7, replace the lambda with Annonymous inner class.